# Scala not found: value error

Tags: scala

I am trying to execute max function in scala shell but getting error in one way

```
scala> def max(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
           if (x > y) x
           else y
         }
  max: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> a =max(10, 20)
<console>:14: error: not found: value a
.....
```

It works when I try like below, but I am trying to understand what is benefit/reason of specifying var/val here ? Why can’t it take var by default ?

```
var a=max(10,20)
```

Scala version is 2.11.11, I am trying to learn scala probably I am missing some basic concepts.

Comment: it's just scala syntax: values must be defined as `val a = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because best practice is to prefer immutable `val`s rather than mutable `var`s.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/best-practice-prefer-immutable-variables-values-in-scala

```
val a = max(10,20)
```

---

> In scala all variables have to be either var or val. Language designed
>   in this way.

Comment: I got an error that means there something wrong, bigger than best practice. Why is this designed in this way ? What  could have gone wrong if language supported this, I mean by default accept function return var.

Comment: What is wrong is you didn't declare `a` as `var` or `val`.

Comment: Why can’t it infer that ? What else it could be when my function return type is Int

Comment: `var` can't be default since it's against best practice. `val` could be default (with explicit `var`) but it was designed differently.

Comment: What do you mean "infer"? Type can be inferred. But both `val a = max(10,20)` and `var a = max(10,20)`  are possible.

Comment: After `var a = max(10,20)` you can do `a = 100` but after `val a = max(10,20)` `a = 100` will not compile.

Comment: Introducing variables automatically when assigning into them might seem like a good idea, but it is prone to scope issues. Just imagine code like: `if (something) {v = 0} else {v = 1};println(v)`. It would also make many typos go unnoticed, like `name = "A";namo = "B"`.

Comment: @Suma and Dmytro I got it now, in scala all variables have to be either var or val. Language designed in this way.

Comment: @DmytroMitin  I can accept your answer if you could update it with my last comment, right now you have given best practice in answer which will be confusing answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Scala variable has to be either var or val, it can’t be inferred.